# Application is not compatible with Nexus 7

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-compatibility, nexus-7

I have following configuration in Manifest file :

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I tried to run my app in Nexus 7 emulator, but it does not run in it. But it opens another emulator. How to run my application in Nexus 7 ?

Comment: Please look at the link in @alex answer. You have CALL_PHONE permission but the Nexus 7 has no phone.

Answer (score 2):

Some permissions imply a `<uses-feature>` element look [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions-features) to see what you need to add as an optional feature.

Answer (score 0):

It will choose the AVD most compatible to the app even-though all your AVD might be compatible. But you are allow to choose which AVD you want to use and force your app to run on specific AVD.

If you are using Eclipse, then:

1. Right Click -> Run As -> Run Configurations
2. In the "Target" tab, you can choose to run on all active AVD or a specific AVD.

Comment: Didn't worked, I just got Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY

Comment: Are you using google-apis in your app? If so, you will need to create an AVD base on google-apis instead of android-sdk.

Comment: This answer is no where near the question. o_O

Answer (score 0):

I think perhaps the problem is that the App requesting permission to things that don't exist on Nexus 7 Tab.
This permission in your manifest implicitly declares the "android.hardware.telephony" feature.
Refer to the document: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#market-feature-filtering

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Try this, keep the permission, but declare the "telephony" feature as false.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"></uses-feature>
```